# how to retrieve different result from entity refers to itself

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have an entity like this :

```
 class Client
    {        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nom { get; set; }
        public string Prenom { get; set; } 
        public Nullable<DateTime> date_naissance { get; set; }
        public Sex? Sexe { get; set; }
        public Client Parent { get; set; }
}
```

and what I want it is when I select a parent,my query's result (I'm using EF6) shows the parent and his clients related to him (like father and his sons).

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to do this - eager loading, lazy loading and explicit loading.
You can read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)